# Count of {field.name} where {field.name} = "No"

Tags: count, crystal-reports, cumulative-sum

Good day; I am looking for help creating a running total or a formula where I can see a count of a specific field that equals "No".
Currently I have a total count of `{ems_SceneCall.CrewDecison}` for all decisions, and now I want to add a count of `{ems_SceneCall.CrewDecison} = "No"`. I have had success with this up to the point where I want to count to reset with each group.
Currently I have a Running Total Set to count the field, Evaluate records where `{ems_SceneCall.CrewDecison} = "No"`, and reset on change of group. This running total only shows 1 or 0.

Comment: Where did you place the running total on your report? Group footer I assume?To test you should place in the details and see what its doing there. And an obvious question I think, you used count and not distinct count?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is a formula that says

```
if {ems_SceneCall.CrewDecison} = "No" then 1 else 0
```

Then create a group summary (SUM) to the group footers